# how to know how many time a Set had found a duplicate value while adding values

Tags: java

i have this `int` array,

```
int [] A = {1,2,3,1,5,2,2,2,2,4,1,2,3,1,1,2,1};
```

Now if i add it in a set it will only add unique values,

```
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        s.add(A[i]); 
}

System.out.println(s.toString());
```

but how would i know that how many times `Set` had encountered a duplicate value ?

for exmaple,

in the above array, on first iteration `1` is added, on 2nd iteration `2` is added , on third iteration `3` is added, but on 4th iteration `1` is skipped.

Now how would i know that `4th` value was skipped by set?

Edit: i don't want to use `s.contains`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a frequency count in Java 8

```
int [] a = {1,2,3,1,5,2,2,2,2,4,1,2,3,1,1,2,1};
Map<Integer, Long> countOfNumbers = IntStream.of(a).boxed()
        .collect(groupingBy(i -> i, counting()));
System.out.println(countOfNumbers);
```

prints

```
{1=6, 2=7, 3=2, 4=1, 5=1}
```

The key will be the number, and the `keySet()` is the set of those keys and the value will be the count.

`Collectors.groupingBy(Function)` builds a Map where the key of the map is the result of the Function, and the value is a list of all the values.

`i -> i` says, I don't want to derive a value or look up a field, I want to use the value as the key.

`counting()` says, I don't want a List of the numbers, I just want to know how many there was.

Comment: can you please elaborate this `groupingBy(i -> i, counting())`

Answer (score 2):

`s.add(A[i])` would return `false` if the element was already in the Set. All you have to do is check the value returned by that method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (!s.add(A[i]))
        System.out.println(A[i] + " is already in the Set"); 
}
```

If you want to know how many times an element wasn't added, maintain a counter.

Answer (score 1):

`add` method returns `false` if object is already added.

[Set API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `com.google.common.collect.Multiset<E>` from the **Guava** library.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int [] A = {1,2,3,1,5,2,2,2,2,4,1,2,3,1,1,2,1};
        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

                System.err.println("index " + i + " "+ s.add(A[i]));

        }
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
```

index 0 true
index 1 true
index 2 true
index 3 false
index 4 true
index 5 false
index 6 false
index 7 false
index 8 false
index 9 true
index 10 false
index 11 false
index 12 false
index 13 false
index 14 false
index 15 false
index 16 false
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3,1,5,2,2,2,2,4,1,2,3,1,1,2,1};

    int count = 0;

    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        if (!s.add(a[i]))
        {
           count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Set had encountered a duplicate value :" + count
            + "times");
```